# JavaScript passing coordinates from one function to another

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am having issues passing two coordinates from one function to another. I don't really know JavaScript, but it seems to be somewhat correct. Could you please let me know where is my error?

```
     <head>
      <script>
       var zoom = 12; // 18 for mobile phones because the geolocation is more accurate 

       function init() {
         // Don't bother if the web browser doesn't support cross-document messaging
         if (window.postMessage) {
           if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
             try {
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pPos) {
               send(pPos.coords.latitude, pPos.coords.longitude);
             }, function() {});
             } catch (e) {}
           } else if (google && google.gears) {
             // Relevant if targeting mobile phones (some of which may have Google Gears)
             try {
               var geoloc = google.gears.factory.create("beta.geolocation");
               geoloc.getCurrentPosition(function(pPos) {
               send(pPos.latitude, pPos.longitude);
             }, function() {});
             } catch (e) {}
           }
         }
       }

       function send(pLat, pLng) {
         var myiframe = document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow;
         // The third parameter, zoom, is optional
         myiframe.postMessage(pLat + "," + pLng + "," + zoom, "http://www.qib.la");
       }

       window.onload=init;
      </script>
     </head>

     <body>
      <iframe id="myiframe" src="http://www.qib.la/embed/" width="400" height="400">
        Check the prayer direction towards the Ka'ba in Makkah at
        <a href="http://www.qib.la/">Qibla Direction</a>.
      </iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/PrayTimes.js"></script>

<br>
<p align="center">Waterloo, ON, Canada<p>
<div align="center" id="table"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var date = new Date(); // today
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, pLat + "," + pLng, -5);
    var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha', 'Midnight'];

    var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</th></tr>';
    for(var i in list)  {
        html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;

</script>


     </body>
```

Is it possible to return a value from an asynchronous function? How do I use a callback here?

Comment: What issues are you having? What is the error?

Comment: I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude here 
 var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, + b + ',' + c + , -5);

Comment: like this 

 var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, + lat + ',' + long + , -5);

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in this code:

```
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, + b + ',' + c + , -5);
```

You have a "+" and then a comma immediately following it. I'm not sure what your intent for the code was, but that is what is causing it to not run.

Perhaps you intended to follow the pattern of appending the commas as strings?

```
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + -5);
```

Or perhaps that -5 was meant to be a separate argument?

```
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, b + ',' + c, -5);
```

Comment: var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, pLat + "," + pLng, -5);
Edited the entire code, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you try and clarify a bit?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the latitude and longitude to this variable 
var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [42.19,-70.72], -5);
Where 42.19,-70.72 are the latitude and longitude values obtained using google geolocation function.